# Black screen if I use displayport

Tags: displayport

I bought a new Asus Rog monitor and Ubuntu does not boot (black screen) if I'm using the display-port. It works with HDMI. Any idea why?

Comment: Could you add details about your GPU, GPU driver version and the OS version.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to use DisplayPort with the default video driver. You have to install AMD / Nvidia's driver, depending on your manufacturer

To install AMD drivers, visit the [official support page](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Install.aspx).

To install Nvidia drivers, [this guide](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2081649) should be of help.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  Would you please expand this answer a bit?  How would the OP go about installing AMD / Nvidia drivers?